# RecyclerView's adapter displays same picture instead of different pictures

Tags: android, firebase

I have an adapter that is supposed to fetch each user's profile picture from Firebase storage and set it in an ImageView, but what happens is, that every time it updates, it changes the same profile picture for all the image views. (So it shows the last fetched picture on all image views). This is the code part of the fetching and setting the picture up:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    myHolder = holder;   

    StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("profilePictures").child(mDataset.get(position));

    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    ref.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {

            Log.d("Tag", "Success");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
            Log.d("Tag", "Failure");
        }
    });

    myHolder.singleItemImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Test"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

mUpdatesReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("timeUpdates");
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            boolean isChanged = false;

            for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               if (time < 180 )){                        
                    if (!myDataset.contains(datas.getKey().toString())){
                        myDataset.add(datas.getKey().toString());
                        isChanged = true;
                    }
                } else {

                    myDataset.remove(datas.getKey().toString());
                    isChanged = true;


                }
                if (isChanged) {
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
}
        mUpdatesReference.addValueEventListener(listener);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: because image downloading is async work when the image downloaded successfully the current view holder index changed to new index 
you must map the index to the bitmap and update adapter

Answer (score 1):

Because you get bitmap and set it out of method and dont release that, it set for all users.
Just change your method to this:

```
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            myHolder = holder;   

            StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("profilePictures").child(mDataset.get(position));

            final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
            ref.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {

                    Log.d("Tag", "Success");
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    if(bitmap!=null)
                    myHolder.singleItemImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    else myHolder.singleItemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.YourPlaceholder); 

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                    Log.d("Tag", "Failure");
                   myHolder.singleItemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.YourPlaceholder); 
                }
            });


        }
```

Comment: You mean move the setting up inside the onSuccess? I tried it, but what's happening is that it constantly changing the images from one to another (Because the adapter is being called from another activity). So now every image view still displays the same image for all, but constantly changing

Comment: ok then you must set a placeholder when user image is not available else set it to imageview. if you dont do this one time bitmap set to imageview that set to all other imageviews. just set placeholder for imageview.

Comment: There is a placeholder in the xml if that's what you mean?

Comment: in xml not work. because you get bitmap and it stay in memory and every time you get one bitmap it set for all imageview.

Comment: Ok, but what I type instead of "yourPlaceholder"? do I need to get some drawable using findViewById? How to get that bitmap placeholder?

Comment: use a picture in your drawable resource and set it to imageview like this: myHolder.singleItemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.YourPlaceholder);

Comment: please add your layout to question.

Comment: I did it, so I guess the problem is somewhere in my activity's code because the problem remains :)

Comment: add your adapter layout and your activity to question. We can solve this :)

Comment: added my activity's code where I set the adapter, it's quite a mess, sorry. You see in the code I listen to changes in the Firebase database, and every change I update the ArrayList with the user that is within the specified time delta

Comment: Are you set "ic_launcher_background" for placeholder in code?

Answer (score 0):

first update your model with Bitmap reference

```
void downloadImage(int rowindex){
StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("profilePictures").child(mDataset.get(rowindex).getId());

    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    ref.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {

            Log.d("Tag", "Success");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            mDataset.get(rowindex).setDownloadedBitmap(bitmap);
            notifyDataSetChanged ();

        }
```

in  onBindViewHolder() add this

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        myHolder = holder; 

     Bitmap currentBitmap=mDataset.get(rowindex).getDownloadedBitmap();
   if(currentBitmap!=null){
     myHolder.singleItemImage.setImageBitmap(currentBitmap);
     }else{
     downloadImage(position);
     myHolder.singleItemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default);
 }

}
```

ProfilePictureItem.java

```
   public class ProfilePictureItem{

    private String key;
    private Bitmap downloadedBitmap;

    public setKey(String key){
     this.key=key;
    }
      public getKey(){
      return key;
     }
     public setDownloadedBitmap(Bitmap downloadedBitmap){
      this.downloadedBitmap=downloadedBitmap;
      }
      public getDownloadedBitmap(){
      return downloadedBitmap;
      }

      }
```

Comment: what are setImageBitmap and getImageBitmap functions? they cannot be resolved

Comment: instead of use list of key Strings create model class Contain key  as string variable and Bitmap reference variable and change list of this model as dataset

Comment: I'm also a beginner with Java, How do I call the ProfilePictureItem from the model? Do I need to type something like `ProfilePictureItem item = new ProfilePictureItem()`?